# How to trigger barcode scan key in android using appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNYS1.png)I have an android device with scanning enabled. Normally we do scanning by pressing a hardware button. How can I automate this process using appium ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Appium desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop), run emulator or real device, setup capabilities in appium desktop like:

```
platformName: 'Android',
deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
appWaitActivity: <activity to be launched on app start>,
appWaitPackage: <your app package>,
app: <path to apk>
```

and start new session.

Here how inspector will look like [image]

Search for your buttons to get unique locators (better to use `resource-id`) and later in test you can click it:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(<button resource_id>)).click()
```

Comment: But I need to press Scan button which is different. Keycode_Button_Scan does not get resolve.

Comment: Is it a physical button on device (power, volume buttons, etc ) or button in your app? If its in the app, then use Appium desktop to investigate

Comment: It a different physical button on device like volume up/down.

Comment: Can you make a photo of device and explain what this button is for when it is not scan app?

Comment: I have attached image in my original post. This button triggers the scanning which is used for reading bar code.

Comment: Just to re-ensure, it's a physical button like lock button in i Phones. Image, I have attached is the key programmer screen in device.